# Anylogic Java Runtimexception

Tags: java, anylogic

My cars arrive leave the process correctly until a certain amount of simulations, following error occurs: Ausnahme während der Ausführung eines diskreten Ereignisses:

`root.carMoveTo1: Car failed to change lane (that was necessary to continue movement) java.lang.RuntimeException: root.carMoveTo1: Car failed to change lane (that was necessary to continue movement)`

looks like my car cant leave the simulation but dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Common problem. One of your roads is too short for an appearing car to switch lane before the end of the lane. Check which lane is associated with `carMoveTo1` and make it longer.